# My script get an url to a subpage in hotels.com but the url go back to how it was before

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Let me explain.

I have this script :

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait     
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By     
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "driver\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,900")
options.add_argument('enable-logging')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
 
url = 'https://fr.hotels.com/ho344560/?q-check-in=2021-06-26&q-check-out=2021-06-27&q-rooms=1&q-room-0-adults=2&q-room-0-children=0&sort-order=BEST_SELLER&WOD=6&WOE=7&JHR=1&FPQ=2&MGT=1&ZSX=0&SYE=3&YGF=1'



driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
time.sleep(2)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="uolsaJ"]'))).click()

reviews = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="WxdyDo _3ZW5IO"]')
reviews.click()
```

The script open this page : [website](https://fr.hotels.com/ho344560/?q-rooms=1&q-room-0-adults=2&q-room-0-children=0)

Next, he is closing the dates option, and closing the cookie options. And then the script goes here :

[image: website]

So, the script ends here :

[image: output]

But my goal is to scrape all the reviews, so I start by get the new url (you can see the new url in the image above) :

```
new_url = driver.current_url

driver.get(new_url)

ratings = []
comments = []
dates = []

results = requests.get(get_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

reviews = soup.find_all('li', class_ = "_1BIjNY")

for review in reviews:
    rating = review.find('div', class_ = '_15NDDt').text.strip()
    ratings.append(rating)
```

And after I get the new url, my script start the scraping. But it seems that the new url reset to the url of the main page.

When this line run :

```
driver.get(new_url)
```

This page should opening :

[image: websitedesired]

But no, the url reset and instead I get the page from the very beginning :

[image: websitenotdesired]

I don't understand why it does that. It's so strange. It's like it's the same URLs but not the same at the same time.

I hope I'm clear, it's a very specific trouble.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import trio
import httpx
import pandas as pd


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client:
        data = {
            "operationName": "reviewsQuery",
            "query": "query reviewsQuery($hotelId: String!, $reviewType: String, $reviewOrder: String, $tripTypeFilter: String, $paginationURL: String) {\n  reviews(\n    hotelId: $hotelId\n    reviewType: $reviewType\n    reviewOrder: $reviewOrder\n    tripTypeFilter: $tripTypeFilter\n    paginationURL: $paginationURL\n  ) {\n    body {\n      reviewContent {\n        filters {\n          type\n          name\n          count\n          url\n          __typename\n        }\n        overall {\n          selectedFilterType\n          rating\n          badgeText\n          total\n          scores {\n            score\n            count\n            url\n            __typename\n          }\n          ratingAspects {\n            cleanliness\n            service\n            comfort\n            condition\n            neighbourhood\n            __typename\n          }\n          whatGuestsSay {\n            type\n            text\n            __typename\n          }\n          topRated {\n            category\n            explanation\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        sort {\n          url\n          options {\n            value\n            label\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        reviews {\n          hermes {\n            groups {\n              separatorText\n              items {\n                itineraryId\n                brand\n                googleTranslateEnabled\n                reviewDbDate\n                ...GuestReviewsFragment\n                __typename\n              }\n              __typename\n            }\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        pagination {\n          currentPage\n          nextURL\n          totalPages\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment GuestReviewsFragment on ReviewsItem {\n  genuineMsg\n  tripType\n  tripTypeText\n  reviewDate\n  reviewSubmitDate\n  rating\n  reviewer {\n    name\n    locality\n    locale\n    __typename\n  }\n  badge\n  summary\n  description\n  __typename\n}\n",
            "variables": {
                "hotelId": "344560",
                "reviewOrder": "date_newest_first",
                "reviewType": "brand",
                "tripTypeFilter": "all"
            }
        }
        r = await client.post('https://fr.hotels.com/kes/graphql', json=data)
        allin = []
        for x in r.json()['data']['reviews']['body']['reviewContent']['reviews']['hermes']['groups']:
            for i in x['items']:
                allin.append(i)
        df = pd.DataFrame(allin)
        print(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

Output:

```
      itineraryId    brand googleTranslateEnabled   reviewDbDate  ...         badge                                      summary                                        description   __typename
0   9187351261582     hcom                   None  1622592000000  ...  Exceptionnel                                               Chambre spacieuse, confortable et très propre....  ReviewsItem
1   9185304165394     hcom                   None  1616716800000  ...  Exceptionnel                                    Très bien                Rien à redire, toit était très bien  ReviewsItem 
2   9203674238030     hcom                   None  1610323200000  ...     Très bien                                               Personnel très accueillant et serviable, très ...  ReviewsItem 
3   9203627838205     hcom                   None  1609891200000  ...  Exceptionnel                                 Bon séjour.   Bon hôtel avec des maisons ce qui change agréa...  ReviewsItem 
4   8171447104204  expedia                   None  1600473600000  ...     Très bien                                               Endroit très calme et bien tenu. Les chambres ...  ReviewsItem 
5   9196245721991     hcom                   None  1597449600000  ...     Très bien  Très bon hôtel pour une étape sans problème                                                     ReviewsItem 
6   9201170054645     hcom                   None  1594166400000  ...  Exceptionnel                 Le bonheur est dans l'hôtel.                                                     ReviewsItem 
7   9195933261527     hcom                   None  1593820800000  ...  Exceptionnel                          Adresse à partager!  Encore merci, nous sommes tres contents de not...  ReviewsItem 
8   9195996228643     hcom                   None  1594771200000  ...     Très bien     Chambres situées dans des maisonnettes    Chambres réparties au rez-de-chaussée de quatr...  ReviewsItem 
9   8157517261407     hcom                   None  1564358400000  ...     Très bien                      Hôtel simple et propre   Hôtel idéalement situé. Bien décoré, chambre u...  ReviewsItem 
10  8129437999689     hcom                   None  1559520000000  ...  Exceptionnel                                               Bon accueil à l arrivée , chambre spacieuse co...  ReviewsItem 
11  8153965827072     hcom                   None  1537142400000  ...  Exceptionnel                                               hôtel calme, proche mer et ile de tascon super...  ReviewsItem 
12  8154341267443     hcom                   None  1531785600000  ...  Exceptionnel                                               Très bon séjour, l'accueil et le personnel ont...  ReviewsItem 
13  8116582132251     hcom                   None  1538956800000  ...     Très bien                                               Très bon accueil. Endroit calme. Chambre spaci...  ReviewsItem 
14  8140934156789     hcom                   None  1537228800000  ...  Exceptionnel                                               Lovely hotel - staff very welcoming and helpfu...  ReviewsItem 
15  8140358896863     hcom                   None  1534118400000  ...  Exceptionnel                                 Goed hotel .  Vriendelijk, hartelijk ontvangst met goede een...  ReviewsItem 
16  8158470224158  expedia                   None  1530576000000  ...  Exceptionnel                       Schönes modernes Hotel  Gute Zwischenstation im Bereich der südlichen ...  ReviewsItem 
17  9201606933776     hcom                   None  1598140800000  ...  Exceptionnel                                                                                                  ReviewsItem 
18  9196045917398     hcom                   None  1593993600000  ...  Exceptionnel                                                                                                  ReviewsItem 
19  8131424254420     hcom                   None  1564358400000  ...     Très bien                                                                                                  ReviewsItem 
20  8118953586144     hcom                   None  1540857600000  ...          Bien                                                                                                  ReviewsItem 

[21 rows x 15 columns]
```

> Note that `df.columns`:

```
Index(['itineraryId', 'brand', 'googleTranslateEnabled', 'reviewDbDate',
       'genuineMsg', 'tripType', 'tripTypeText', 'reviewDate',
       'reviewSubmitDate', 'rating', 'reviewer', 'badge', 'summary',
       'description', '__typename'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Wouah wouah wouah, wonderful ! I will try that

Comment: It's working, that's awesome. i don' t understand your code but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Do you know how to create a csv file out of your script ? With the data in the output

Comment: @RandallCloud change `print(df)` to be `df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)`

Comment: Yeah, obviously. Thanks, also, I for clarity's sake I just put on URL, but I have an list of URLs hotels. How to implement your code into a loop ? like  `for url in urls :`

Comment: @RandallCloud you can loop over the `hotelId` which is actually presented within the url which you provided. so you've to collect it from the urls which you've.

Comment: Yeah ok I will try, I keep you in touch. Thanks again. And just in case : `df.to_csv('data.csv',sep=';', index=False, encoding = 'utf-8-sig')` works better :)

Comment: @RandallCloud i assume you are dealing with `Windows`, that's why you needed the encoding as you are dealing with Unicode chars in french language.

Comment: OOOoh I see :) Thanks

Comment: I made it, I built the loop. Do you think you could help me with the same problem but on another website ? (booking.com)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the page uses JS- perhaps you can try figuring out the exact calls and execute some JS to get the desired result?

Comment: I don't even know how to use JS :/ I'm kind of knowing only python.