# Handling POST Request in expedia.com

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, post, python-requests, httpx

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68181863/my-script-get-an-url-to-a-subpage-in-hotels-com-but-the-url-go-back-to-how-it-wa), the answer to this question shows how to handle POST request for hotels.com

here is the code made by  [αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7658985/%ce%b1%d4%8b%c9%b1%d2%bd%d4%83-%ce%b1%d0%bc%d1%94%d1%8f%ce%b9c%ce%b1%ce%b7)

```
import trio
import httpx
import pandas as pd


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client:
        data = {
            "operationName": "reviewsQuery",
            "query": "query reviewsQuery($hotelId: String!, $reviewType: String, $reviewOrder: String, $tripTypeFilter: String, $paginationURL: String) {\n  reviews(\n    hotelId: $hotelId\n    reviewType: $reviewType\n    reviewOrder: $reviewOrder\n    tripTypeFilter: $tripTypeFilter\n    paginationURL: $paginationURL\n  ) {\n    body {\n      reviewContent {\n        filters {\n          type\n          name\n          count\n          url\n          __typename\n        }\n        overall {\n          selectedFilterType\n          rating\n          badgeText\n          total\n          scores {\n            score\n            count\n            url\n            __typename\n          }\n          ratingAspects {\n            cleanliness\n            service\n            comfort\n            condition\n            neighbourhood\n            __typename\n          }\n          whatGuestsSay {\n            type\n            text\n            __typename\n          }\n          topRated {\n            category\n            explanation\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        sort {\n          url\n          options {\n            value\n            label\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        reviews {\n          hermes {\n            groups {\n              separatorText\n              items {\n                itineraryId\n                brand\n                googleTranslateEnabled\n                reviewDbDate\n                ...GuestReviewsFragment\n                __typename\n              }\n              __typename\n            }\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        pagination {\n          currentPage\n          nextURL\n          totalPages\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment GuestReviewsFragment on ReviewsItem {\n  genuineMsg\n  tripType\n  tripTypeText\n  reviewDate\n  reviewSubmitDate\n  rating\n  reviewer {\n    name\n    locality\n    locale\n    __typename\n  }\n  badge\n  summary\n  description\n  __typename\n}\n",
            "variables": {
                "hotelId": "344560",
                "reviewOrder": "date_newest_first",
                "reviewType": "brand",
                "tripTypeFilter": "all"
            }
        }
        r = await client.post('https://fr.hotels.com/kes/graphql', json=data)
        allin = []
        for x in r.json()['data']['reviews']['body']['reviewContent']['reviews']['hermes']['groups']:
            for i in x['items']:
                allin.append(i)
        df = pd.DataFrame(allin)
        print(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

I have two questions related to this:

1. How the above code, because the above code is not able to extract all the reviews it just extracts 50 reviews, I am trying to understand how to read the POST query here
2. 

How to modify the code for expedia.com I tried above method for expedia.com but it did not work, here :

```
import trio
import httpx
import pandas as pd


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client:
        data = {
            "operationName": "reviewsQuery",
            "query": "query reviewsQuery($hotelId: String!, $reviewType: String, $reviewOrder: String, $tripTypeFilter: String, $paginationURL: String) {\n  reviews(\n    hotelId: $hotelId\n    reviewType: $reviewType\n    reviewOrder: $reviewOrder\n    tripTypeFilter: $tripTypeFilter\n    paginationURL: $paginationURL\n  ) {\n    body {\n      reviewContent {\n        filters {\n          type\n          name\n          count\n          url\n          __typename\n        }\n        overall {\n          selectedFilterType\n          rating\n          badgeText\n          total\n          scores {\n            score\n            count\n            url\n            __typename\n          }\n          ratingAspects {\n            cleanliness\n            service\n            comfort\n            condition\n            neighbourhood\n            __typename\n          }\n          whatGuestsSay {\n            type\n            text\n            __typename\n          }\n          topRated {\n            category\n            explanation\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        sort {\n          url\n          options {\n            value\n            label\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        reviews {\n          hermes {\n            groups {\n              separatorText\n              items {\n                itineraryId\n                brand\n                googleTranslateEnabled\n                reviewDbDate\n                ...GuestReviewsFragment\n                __typename\n              }\n              __typename\n            }\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        pagination {\n          currentPage\n          nextURL\n          totalPages\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment GuestReviewsFragment on ReviewsItem {\n  genuineMsg\n  tripType\n  tripTypeText\n  reviewDate\n  reviewSubmitDate\n  rating\n  reviewer {\n    name\n    locality\n    locale\n    __typename\n  }\n  badge\n  summary\n  description\n  __typename\n}\n",
            "variables": {
                "hotelId": "344560",
                "reviewOrder": "date_newest_first",
                "reviewType": "brand",
                "tripTypeFilter": "all"
            }
        }
        r = await client.post('https://fr.expedia.com/kes/graphql', json=data)
        allin = []
        for x in r.json()['data']['reviews']['body']['reviewContent']['reviews']['hermes']['groups']:
            for i in x['items']:
                allin.append(i)
        df = pd.DataFrame(allin)
        print(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

here is the error
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py in map_exceptions(map)
9     try:
---> 10         yield
11     except Exception as exc:  # noqa: PIE786

31 frames

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ConnectError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

ConnectError: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ConnectError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

```
[... skipping hidden 1 frame]
```

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py in map_httpcore_exceptions()
75
76         message = str(exc)
---> 77         raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
78
79

ConnectError: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

here is the another code I tried this one showed  requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url: https://www.expedia.com/graphql

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

def main():
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0"
    }

    data = [
        {
            "operationName": "PropertyFilteredReviewsQuery",
            "variables": {
                "context": {
                    "siteId": 1,
                    "locale": "en_US",
                    "eapid": 0,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "device": {
                        "type": "DESKTOP"
                    },
                    "identity": {
                        "duaid": "-1",
                        "expUserId": "832921361",
                        "tuid": "-1",
                        "authState": "ANONYMOUS"
                    },
                    "privacyTrackingState": "CAN_TRACK",
                    "debugContext": {
                        "abacusOverrides": [],
                        "alterMode": "RELEASED"
                    }
                },
                "propertyId": "24625",
                "searchCriteria": {
                    "primary": {
                        "dateRange": None,
                        "rooms": [{"adults": 2}],
                        "destination": {"regionId": "178305"}
                    },
                    "secondary": {
                        "booleans": [
                            {"id": "includeRecentReviews", "value": True},
                            {"id": "includeRatingsOnlyReviews", "value": True},
                            {"id": "overrideEmbargoForIndividualReviews", "value": True}
                        ],
                        "counts": [{"id": "startIndex", "value": 0}, {"id": "size", "value": 10}],
                        "selections": [{"id": "sortBy", "value": "NEWEST_TO_OLDEST_BY_LANGUAGE"}, {"id": "searchTerm", "value": ""}]
                    }
                }
            },
            "query": "query PropertyFilteredReviewsQuery($context: ContextInput!, $propertyId: String!, $searchCriteria: PropertySearchCriteriaInput!) {\n  propertyReviewSummaries(\n    context: $context\n    propertyIds: [$propertyId]\n    searchCriteria: $searchCriteria\n  ) {\n    ...__PropertyReviewSummaryFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  propertyInfo(context: $context, propertyId: $propertyId) {\n    id\n    reviewInfo(searchCriteria: $searchCriteria) {\n      ...__PropertyReviewsListFragment\n      sortAndFilter {\n        ...TravelerTypeFragment\n        ...SortTypeFragment\n        ...SearchTextFragment\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\n... (rest of the GraphQL query) ..."
        }
    ]

    response = requests.post("https://www.expedia.com/graphql", json=data, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()

    allin = []
    for x in response.json()[0]['data']['propertyInfo']['reviewInfo']['reviews']['content']['reviews']:
        allin.append(x)
    df = pd.DataFrame(allin)
    print(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is the error? Where is the error occurring?

Comment: I'll take a look but at first glance https://fr.expedia.com/kes/graphql hostname does not resolve. https://expedia.com/kes/graphql does.

Comment: What is an example URL where you are capturing the call "reviewsQuery". If I click on a property and view the reviews I see a call to "PropertyFilteredReviewsQuery". Just curious. also in my last comment I meant "https://expedia.com/graphql" resolves.

Comment: You need to be querying https://expedia.com/graphql and it seems like your json payload is incomplete. It returns a 200 but a msg of "Validate GraphQL failed". I'm able to fetch the reviews by querying PropertyFilteredReviewsQuery with a valid payload. I'm not sure where you got reviewsQuery from but if you tell me I can see if I can get it to work

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow I tried that let me put that code above

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow I tried the PropertyFilteredReviewsQuery i have placed my code in the above post, but still got the error, could you please check my playload if I am putting it correct. Also are you able to extract all the reviews (there are more than 1000+ reviews for this hotel https://www.expedia.com/San-Francisco-Hotels-Hyatt-Centric-Fishermans-Wharf-San-Francisco.h22500.Hotel-Information. The post request is made when "See all reviews" button is clicked

Comment: Your example works for me if I use requests and add 'client-info' into the headers. I think it's because httpx adds a 'host' in the headers which triggers a 403 response. If you try it with requests it works(w/ client-info)

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow could you please tell how are you defining the payload

Comment: I used the same payload as is in your EDIT but I changed "duaid" and "tuid" both to "-1" and "authstate" to "ANONYMOUS". I set headers = {'client-info': '[pulled from browser]'}. If you make those changes and use requests library it works. httpx returns a 403 but I haven't quite figured out why yet.

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow I made the changes you mentioned and placed my code in the above post, but it still did not work, could you please check this one, this time error (technically it is not an error) it is  429 of too many requests

Comment: 429 means you just have to wait. Try again later and see what response you get but your headers are wrong. It requires a 'client-info' header. Inspect the request in your browser and you will see it. Also I mistakenly said to set "duaid" to "-1" I meant "expUserId"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me but I did not look into how client-info and duaid are generated.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

def main():
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        'Client-Info': "blossom-flex-ui,9382ef788e9311fcea3ce7a7b749cd68c4059a45,us-west-2",  # not sure where this comes from just took it from browser dev tools
    }

    data = [
  {
    "operationName": "PropertyFilteredReviewsQuery",
    "variables": {
      "context": {
        "siteId": 1,
        "locale": "en_US",
        "eapid": 0,
        "currency": "USD",
        "device": {
          "type": "DESKTOP"
        },
        "identity": {
          "duaid": "1003be2b-6834-4cf8-bb66-66a49107b76c",  # not sure where this comes from just took it from browser dev tools
          "expUserId": "-1",
          "tuid": "-1",
          "authState": "ANONYMOUS"
        },
        "privacyTrackingState": "CAN_TRACK",
        "debugContext": {
          "abacusOverrides": [],
          "alterMode": "RELEASED"
        }
      },
      "propertyId": "24625",
      "searchCriteria": {
        "primary": {
          "dateRange": None,
          "rooms": [
            {
              "adults": 2
            }
          ],
          "destination": {
            "regionId": "178305"
          }
        },
        "secondary": {
          "booleans": [
            {
              "id": "includeRecentReviews",
              "value": True
            },
            {
              "id": "includeRatingsOnlyReviews",
              "value": True
            },
            {
              "id": "overrideEmbargoForIndividualReviews",
              "value": True
            }
          ],
          "counts": [
            {
              "id": "startIndex",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "id": "size",
              "value": 10
            }
          ],
          "selections": [
            {
              "id": "sortBy",
              "value": "NEWEST_TO_OLDEST_BY_LANGUAGE"
            },
            {
              "id": "searchTerm",
              "value": ""
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "query": "query PropertyFilteredReviewsQuery($context: ContextInput!, $propertyId: String!, $searchCriteria: PropertySearchCriteriaInput!) {\n  propertyReviewSummaries(\n    context: $context\n    propertyIds: [$propertyId]\n    searchCriteria: $searchCriteria\n  ) {\n    ...__PropertyReviewSummaryFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  propertyInfo(context: $context, propertyId: $propertyId) {\n    id\n    reviewInfo(searchCriteria: $searchCriteria) {\n      ...__PropertyReviewsListFragment\n      sortAndFilter {\n        ...TravelerTypeFragment\n        ...SortTypeFragment\n        ...SearchTextFragment\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment __PropertyReviewSummaryFragment on PropertyReviewSummary {\n  accessibilityLabel\n  overallScoreWithDescriptionA11y {\n    ...LodgingEnrichedMessageFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  propertyReviewCountDetails {\n    fullDescription\n    __typename\n  }\n  ...ReviewDisclaimerFragment\n  reviewSummaryDetails {\n    label\n    ratingPercentage\n    formattedRatingOutOfMax\n    __typename\n  }\n  totalCount {\n    raw\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ReviewDisclaimerFragment on PropertyReviewSummary {\n  reviewDisclaimer\n  reviewDisclaimerHeading\n  strategy\n  reviewDisclaimerValues {\n    text\n    __typename\n  }\n  reviewDisclaimerLabel\n  reviewDisclaimerAnalytics {\n    referrerId\n    linkName\n    __typename\n  }\n  reviewDisclaimerUrl {\n    value\n    accessibilityLabel\n    link {\n      url\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  reviewDisclaimerAccessibilityLabel\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment LodgingEnrichedMessageFragment on LodgingEnrichedMessage {\n  __typename\n  subText\n  value\n  theme\n  state\n  accessibilityLabel\n  icon {\n    id\n    size\n    theme\n    __typename\n  }\n  mark {\n    id\n    __typename\n  }\n  egdsMark {\n    url {\n      value\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment __PropertyReviewsListFragment on PropertyReviews {\n  summary {\n    paginateAction {\n      text\n      analytics {\n        referrerId\n        linkName\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  reviews {\n    contentDirectFeedbackPromptId\n    ...ReviewParentFragment\n    managementResponses {\n      ...ReviewChildFragment\n      __typename\n    }\n    reviewInteractionSections {\n      primaryDisplayString\n      reviewInteractionType\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  ...NoResultsMessageFragment\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ReviewParentFragment on PropertyReview {\n  id\n  superlative\n  locale\n  title\n  brandType\n  reviewScoreWithDescription {\n    label\n    value\n    __typename\n  }\n  text\n  seeMoreAnalytics {\n    linkName\n    referrerId\n    __typename\n  }\n  submissionTime {\n    longDateFormat\n    __typename\n  }\n  impressionAnalytics {\n    event\n    referrerId\n    __typename\n  }\n  themes {\n    ...ReviewThemeFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  reviewFooter {\n    ...PropertyReviewFooterSectionFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  ...FeedbackIndicatorFragment\n  ...AuthorFragment\n  ...PhotosFragment\n  ...TravelersFragment\n  ...ReviewTranslationInfoFragment\n  ...PropertyReviewSourceFragment\n  ...PropertyReviewRegionFragment\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment AuthorFragment on PropertyReview {\n  reviewAuthorAttribution {\n    text\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment PhotosFragment on PropertyReview {\n  id\n  photoSection {\n    imageClickAnalytics {\n      referrerId\n      linkName\n      __typename\n    }\n    exitAnalytics {\n      referrerId\n      linkName\n      __typename\n    }\n    navClickAnalytics {\n      referrerId\n      linkName\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  photos {\n    description\n    url\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment TravelersFragment on PropertyReview {\n  travelers\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ReviewThemeFragment on ReviewThemes {\n  icon {\n    id\n    __typename\n  }\n  label\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment FeedbackIndicatorFragment on PropertyReview {\n  reviewInteractionSections {\n    primaryDisplayString\n    accessibilityLabel\n    reviewInteractionType\n    feedbackAnalytics {\n      linkName\n      referrerId\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ReviewTranslationInfoFragment on PropertyReview {\n  translationInfo {\n    loadingTranslationText\n    targetLocale\n    translatedBy {\n      description\n      __typename\n    }\n    translationCallToActionLabel\n    seeOriginalText\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment PropertyReviewSourceFragment on PropertyReview {\n  propertyReviewSource {\n    accessibilityLabel\n    graphic {\n      description\n      id\n      size\n      token\n      url {\n        value\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    text {\n      value\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment PropertyReviewRegionFragment on PropertyReview {\n  reviewRegion {\n    id\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment PropertyReviewFooterSectionFragment on PropertyReviewFooterSection {\n  messages {\n    seoStructuredData {\n      itemscope\n      itemprop\n      itemtype\n      content\n      __typename\n    }\n    text {\n      ... on EGDSPlainText {\n        text\n        __typename\n      }\n      ... on EGDSGraphicText {\n        text\n        graphic {\n          ... on Mark {\n            description\n            id\n            size\n            url {\n              ... on HttpURI {\n                relativePath\n                value\n                __typename\n              }\n              __typename\n            }\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ReviewChildFragment on ManagementResponse {\n  id\n  header {\n    text\n    __typename\n  }\n  response\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment NoResultsMessageFragment on PropertyReviews {\n  noResultsMessage {\n    __typename\n    ...MessagingCardFragment\n    ...EmptyStateFragment\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment MessagingCardFragment on UIMessagingCard {\n  graphic {\n    __typename\n    ... on Icon {\n      id\n      description\n      __typename\n    }\n  }\n  primary\n  secondaries\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment EmptyStateFragment on UIEmptyState {\n  heading\n  body\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment TravelerTypeFragment on SortAndFilterViewModel {\n  sortAndFilter {\n    name\n    label\n    options {\n      label\n      isSelected\n      optionValue\n      description\n      clickAnalytics {\n        linkName\n        referrerId\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment SortTypeFragment on SortAndFilterViewModel {\n  sortAndFilter {\n    name\n    label\n    clickAnalytics {\n      linkName\n      referrerId\n      __typename\n    }\n    options {\n      label\n      isSelected\n      optionValue\n      description\n      clickAnalytics {\n        linkName\n        referrerId\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment SearchTextFragment on SortAndFilterViewModel {\n  sortAndFilter {\n    name\n    label\n    graphic {\n      ... on Icon {\n        description\n        id\n        token\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n"
  }
]

    response = requests.post("https://www.expedia.com/graphql", json=data, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()

    allin = pd.DataFrame()
    for x in response.json()[0]['data']['propertyInfo']['reviewInfo']['reviews']:
        review = {
            'title': x['title'],
            'superlative': x['superlative'],
            'text': x['text'],
        }
        allin = pd.concat([allin, pd.DataFrame([review])])
    print(allin)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I noticed that the `duaid` comes from the endpoint `https://www.expedia.com/api/ucs/shortlist//fetch/?clientId=flex`

the request to that endpoint requires a client-token which is in a  tag when the page loads. I haven't checked if it can be obtained using requests since it is presumably javascript. But this should be a start in the right direction. You need the right duaid and client-info token to automate making these calls.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code, I waited for one whole day, and I am still getting 429 message, I tried on google colab it worked, and could you please tell are you able to get all the reviews, there are over 1000+ reviews, because when I tried it only showed limited number of reviews only when I change "value": 10 to a fixed number